# Is the word "until" thought of as belonging to a temporal context?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I speak German and I'd usually translate "bis" into "until". However, it occurred to me that the word "until" is almost always used in a temporal context. Or at least much more often than the German "bis", which would be used both in the phrase "from here *to* there/von da *bis* dort" and "from now *until* then/von jetzt *bis* dann". As far as I can remember, most of the time I read it, *until* seems to denote a date of something to happen.

Is the word *until* thought of as belonging to a temporal context, as opposed to an abstract boundary?

Comment: I would suggest first consulting a dictionary; a list may be found at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2573/13812. I looked in 3 or 4; all of them defined *until* as relating to times or events.

Comment: I think this is general reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***to*** and ***up to*** are for broader use like *bis*.

*until* is almost exclusively used with reference to time.

For your example, *to* is better than *until* even in a temporal context. "From Monday to Friday".

Answer (score 5):

You are correct.  "From here until there" is ungrammatical.  "From tomorrow until Tuesday" is OK.  You should only use "until" to talk about time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your statement that "until" is always used as a temporal adverb, and [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&from=fx3&search=until) seems to support my view.